# Accessing Google Fit data based on time of their creation

Tags: google-api, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

When [querying Google Fit for a data](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/datasets#get_a_dataset), it is possible to specify a time range filter. This time range takes into account only a date of data measurement, not a date when the particular piece of data was created.

For example, if I manually log on 22th of September that I was running for 2 hours on 19th and 21th of September and then issue a request for activities with a time range from 20th to 24th (inclusive), I will get only a single activity from 21th of September back.

**Is there a way to query for data based on a time of when were they added to Google Fit?** We're building an app that will periodically download data from Google Fit and we'd like to be able to download only the data that were added since the last download.

Comment: Nikola, Did you manage to get this working? I am struggling to pull data that were added to Fit from the last time I checked. The start-end time format for querying activities does not help much in obtaining new values added to fit.

Comment: Hey did you get this working?